# Why do we even need anything other than POST and GET HTTP protocols?

Tags: node.js, express, http, post, get

Why can we not just use POST and GET? I feel like everything that PUT PATCH DELETE etc can do can also be done by POST and GET, plus it’s a lot simpler.

Comment: You could. The whole point is to separate concerns, just like code in general. Not sure what you mean by “it’s a lot simpler”, it isn’t; it’s more complex because you lose a standard mechanism of differentiating requests and have to overload two verbs in order to deliberately ignore the others, and explain to API consumers why they’re being ignored, and possibly route those verbs to their non-standard handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Each HTTP verb has a very specific semantic to guide it's usage. Yes, you can use POST to update or delete something in the server, or even use GET method to do any changes, but using PATCH and DELETE for instance makes it much more clear to whoever human is reading it. Also you can have the same URL path with different behavior according to the HTTP verb.